# Survey123 fails accessibility checks. How to fix?

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-survey123, accessibility

We have a very simple 5 question Survey123 application containing a map-based question followed by a couple of multiple choice questions.

Our comms team have run it through an accessibility checker and it shows several fail errors, meaning they won't allow the Survey123 to be published and shared with the public. As far as I'm aware, there is minimal functionality to improve accessibility requirements for Survey123 (and other ArcGIS Online web apps...). I can't go in and directly edit the HTML as far as I'm aware.

What are my options? Is there an official statement or document from Esri which I can send to my comms team to re-assure them that the app is indeed accessible?

WAVE accessibility tool shows these errors (the low contrast relate to the red asterisks against a white background that appear next to required questions):

[image: WAVE accessibility checker results]

Comment: Would contact Esri support for Survey123 support

Comment: Yeah Esri initially refer you to the official accessibility report for Survey123, which doesn't include anything about how to remediate/fix issues identified.

https://www.esri.com/content/dam/esrisites/en-us/media/legal/vpats/arcgis-survey123-313-vpat.pdf.